# How to have a better edit options in gist.github?

Tags: github

I started to create a toturial here: gist.github.com/stavalfi/1020abe20960c2daf215410da56250eb But the edit window is too small and I can't see the privew befor I commit the changes I did in the edit.

How can I change that?

Comment: Have you already created a repo? Or are you starting all from nothing?

Comment: I created one: https://github.com/stavalfi/java-intellij-test/blob/master/README.md here is what I got so far

Comment: Looks like you already have it figured out. What exactly are you wanting to do that you're having an issue with?

Comment: Okay I found out now here: https://gist.github.com/stavalfi/1020abe20960c2daf215410da56250eb what I need but the edit window is too small and I can't see the privew befor I commit the changes I did in the edit.

Comment: Those are two different questions. You don't see the "Preview" button on the top left, and that you want the edit area to be larger. Your question needs to pick one and edit to focus on that, otherwise it's unclear what you're asking

Comment: Fixed, You are right, that wasnt clear.